# How to quickly find files in big Android Studio Project

Tags: android-studio

I want to know that how can I find the files (java files, Kotlin files, xml files) in a big Android Project having hundred of files.
Like since yesterday I am trying to find a Kotlin file inside my project which is associated with a xml file. I was somehow able to find the xml file but now I don't know in which Kotlin file this xml is used.

It consumes a lot of time to search for files when you are working on a big project which is built by other people so is there any way I can easily navigate files in Android Studio.

Please let me know it will be very helpful and will save lot of my time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the file name then do Double shift and then write the name of the file.

Or if you have found the xml file then do write click on the xml file in the project structure and then click find Usages menu or shortcut is Alt+F7

Answer (score 1):

Menu : Edit -> Find -> Find to open find a search box or On a Windows or Linux based machine use shortcut Ctrl + Shift + F to search any string in whole project. ...
On OSX use the Command key instead of Ctrl .
Use Ctrl + F combination for Windows and Linux to search in current file.
Secon